# Python HTMLParser dividing data at &

Tags: python, escaping, html-parsing

I'm using a simple HTMLParser to parse a webpage with code that is always well-formed (it's automatically generated). It works well, until it hits a piece of data with an '&' sign in it - it seems to think that that makes it two separate pieces of data and processes them separately. (That is, it calls "handle_data" twice.) I at first thought that unescaping the '&'would solve the issue, but I don't think it does. Does anyone have any suggestion for how I can get my parser to treat, for instance "Paradise Bakery and Cafe" (that is, "Paradise Bakery & Café") as a single data item rather than as two?

Thanks a lot, 
  bsg

P.S. Please don't tell me that I really should be using BeautifulSoup. I know. But in this case, I knew the markup was guaranteed to be well-formed every time, and I found HTMLParser easier to work with than BeautifulSoup. Thanks.

I'm adding my code - thanks!

```
#this class, extending HTMLParser, is written to process HTML within a <ul>. 
#There are 6 <a> elements nested within each <li>, and I need the data from the second 
#one. Whenever it encounters an <li> tag, it sets the 'is_li' flag to true and resets 
#the count of a's seen to 0; whenever it encounters an <a> tag, it increments the count
#by 1.   When handle_data is called, it checks to make sure that the data is within
#1)an li element and 2) an a element, and that the a element is the second one in that
#li (num_as == 2). If so, it adds the data to the list. 

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
pages = []
is_li = 'false'
#is_li 
num_as = 0

def _init_(self):
    HTMLParser._init_(self)
    self.pages = []
    self.is_li = 'false'
    self.num_as = 0
    self.close_a = 'false'
    sel.close_li = 'false'
    print "initialized"


def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
      if tag == 'li':
          self.is_li = 'true'
          self.close_a = 'false'
          self.close_li = 'false'


      if tag == 'a' and self.is_li == 'true':
          if self.num_as < 7:
              self.num_as += 1
              self.close_a = 'false'

          else:
              self.num_as = 0
              self.is_li = 'false'

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
     if tag == 'a':
         self.close_a = 'true'

     if tag == 'li':
         self.close_li = 'true'
         self.num_as = 0

def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.is_li == 'true':
        if self.num_as == 2 and self.close_li == 'false' and self.close_a == 'false':
            print "found data",  data
            self.pages.append(data)

def get_pages(self):
    return self.pages
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `&` is the beginning of an HTML entity. A displayed `&` should be represented as `&amp;` in the HTML (though browsers will display an `&` followed by a space as an ampersand, I believe that technically this is invalid).

You'll just need to write your `handle_data()` to accommodate the multiple calls, for example using a member variable that gets set to `[]` when you see your start tag and is appended to by each call to `handle_data()` and is then joined into a string when you see your end tag.

I've taken a whack at it below.  The key lines I added have a `# *****` comment. I also took the liberty of using proper Booleans for your flags rather than strings, as it allows the code to be much cleaner (hopefully I didn't mess that up). I also changed your `__init__()` to a `reset()` method (so that your parser object can be reused) and removed the superfluous class variables. Finally, I added `handle_entityref()` and `handle_charref()` methods to handle escaped character entities.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.pages    = []
        self.text     = []                     # *****
        self.is_li    = False
        self.num_as   = 0
        self.close_a  = False
        self.close_li = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
          if tag == 'li':
              self.is_li    = True
              self.close_a  = False
              self.close_li = False

          if tag == 'a' and self.is_li:
              if self.num_as < 7:
                  self.num_as += 1
                  self.close_a = False
              else:
                  self.num_as = 0
                  self.is_li = False

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
         if tag == 'a':
             self.close_a  = True
         if tag == 'li':
             self.close_li = True
             self.num_as   = 0
             self.pages.append("".join(self.text))      # *****
             self.text = []                             # *****

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.is_li:
            if self.num_as == 2 and not self.close_li and not self.close_a:
                print "found data",  data
                self.text.append(data)              # *****

    def handle_charref(self, ref):
        self.handle_entityref("#" + ref)

    def handle_entityref(self, ref):
        self.handle_data(self.unescape("&%s;" % ref))

    def get_pages(self):
        return self.pages
```

The basic idea is that rather than appending to `self.pages` on each call to `handle_data()` you instead append to `self.text`. Then you find some other event that will happen once for each text element (I chose when you see a `</li>` tag but it might be when you see `</a>`, I can't really tell without seeing some of your data too), join up those bits of text, and append *that* to `pages`.

Hopefully this will give you an idea of the approach I'm talking about even if the exact code I posted doesn't work for you.

Comment: It worked beautifully - thank you so much! And thanks for cleaning up my code - believe it or not, my self-taught Python skills somehow did not include the correct way of doing Booleans.

Comment: It ran??? Not bad considering all the changes I made and that I didn't actually try it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unescaping `&` would result strange behaviour at all `&amp;`. I made a class which does not split data into chunks at `&` entities. You can find it [HERE](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578787/).